# Проблема с HTTP DELETE

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

**Доброго времени!**

Использую Rails 4.0.0. Все, вроде бы ок, да вот только возникла проблема при работе с "link_to"-хелпером.  Как вы знаете, в RESTful интерфейсах в Rails экшены "show" и "destroy" контроллера различаются лишь HTTP глаголом( в первом случае это GET, во втором DELETE ). Так вот, собственно, использование хелпера:

```
...
<%= link_to "DELETE IT", item_path(i), method: :delete, :confirm => "?" %>
...
```

не работает, как предполагается. Происходит отправка GET запроса, а не DELETE...
В чем тут может быть дело, друзья?

**UPD:**

Маршруты( из config/routes.db )  [как понимаю, дело в них?]:

```
resources :items
root 'items#index'
```

Comment: Для полноты добавьте, пожалуйста, маршруты (routes.rb), связанные с item.

Comment: @Stanislaw Pankevich, готово.

Answer (score 2):

Подозреваю, что у вас происходит обычный переход на страницу, а браузер в этом случае умеет отправлять либо GET, либо POST. DELETE/PUT-запрос формируется только через `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Да, в большинстве случаев( если не всегда ) это так. Поэтому в приложение включается GEM:

      gem 'jquery-rails'

и у меня он подключен, да вот только проку нет.

Comment: Не в этом проблема? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9945611/238336

Comment: Да, именно она. Странно, почему об этом нигде явно не упоминается...Что ж, все работает! Спасибо, что подкинули статью =)